# Angular-Google-Maps library not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use angularjs and node for my application, and I want to integrate google maps in my app.
I use this set of directives http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/,

Problem that is showing up is this:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]    h  ttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=VisualiseATM&p1=Err…    at%20Mc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)
at angular.min.js:6
at angular.min.js:41
at q (angular.min.js:7)
at g (angular.min.js:40)
at db (angular.min.js:45)
at c (angular.min.js:21)
at Mc (angular.min.js:21)
at qe (angular.min.js:20)
at angular.min.js:331
at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:37)
```

Specifically, it's problem with:

> Module 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Here is my angular code:

```
var app = angular.module("VisualiseATM", [ 'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
'ui.router'
, 'controllers'
, 'ngCookies'
, ]);

app.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    key: 'MY_API_KEY',
    v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
});
})

app.config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function(GoogleMapApiProviders) {
    GoogleMapApiProviders.configure({
        china: true
    });
}]
);
```

I found this on internet, but I'm not sure how to use it in my app.
https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1489

I'm awared that I have to use this angular-simple-logger, but don't know how to integrate it with my code.

I hope that you'll give me an answer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Have you loaded `angular-google-maps.js` into your document?

Comment: I have installed it using npm install and I include it in my document. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: check calling the lib after angular library and before your application script

Comment: Use [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/). It is actively maintained and doesn't have dependencies on lodash and angular-simple-logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Angular-Google-Maps is no longer maintained

Instead use [`AngularJS-Google-Maps`](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ngmap"></script>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/qu60fa8G0XvOm8z8IM0T?p=preview)

---

OR use Angular-Google-Maps **older version 2.1.6.** It doesn't need angular-simple-logger:

```
  <head>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-google-maps@2.1.6"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Angular Google Maps</h1>
  </body>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/N7TVZLDwcwxyecyfNTxe?p=preview).

> ### Angular-Google-Maps
>
> ### Project No longer actively maintained
>
> With angular 2 and other competing projects we have decided to announce that this project is no longer activley maintained. If someone desires to take over the project please contact any of the admins.
>
> As a warning this project is not activley watched by the admins and is checked [from time to time] to fix any major issues. Therefore if something is **major**, contact someone directly via mentioning a users name/alias (will notify the user/admin).
>
> Alternatives:
>
> - [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)
> - [angular2-google-maps](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps)
>
> [— GitHub Angular-Google-Maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps)

Comment: Thank you, I used angularjs-google-maps, but I had to include this in my document:

<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>

You can find example here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/iYYRyr?p=preview

Comment: `angularjs-google-maps` is available on [UNPKG CDN](https://unpkg.com) as https://unpkg.com/ngmap